# S3 Uploader net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET on Video

Tags: javascript, amazon-s3

I'm using https://github.com/odysseyscience/react-s3-uploader and it's been working great. I'm uploading loads of different files etc and it's been fine- but has suddenly started failing on video with the error: net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET

I'm presigning URLs with this

```
   String ext = objectName.substring(objectName.lastIndexOf('.') + 1,objectName.length()).toLowerCase();

        GeneratePresignedUrlRequest generatePresignedUrlRequest
                = new GeneratePresignedUrlRequest(showhowBucket, "assets/" + objectName , HttpMethod.PUT);

        switch(ext){
            case "png":
              generatePresignedUrlRequest.withContentType("image/png");
              break;
            case "jpg":
                generatePresignedUrlRequest.withContentType("image/jpg");
                break;
            case "jpeg":
                generatePresignedUrlRequest.withContentType("image/jpg");
                break;
            case "mp4":
                generatePresignedUrlRequest.withContentType("video/mp4");
                break;
            case "mp3":
                generatePresignedUrlRequest.withContentType("audio/mp3");
                break;
            case "m4u":
                generatePresignedUrlRequest.withContentType("audio/mpeg");
                break;
            case "zip":
                generatePresignedUrlRequest.withContentType("application/x-zip-compressed");
                break;
        }


        // setting additional params: expiration date , content-type, etc
        long expiration = System.currentTimeMillis() + 36000000;
        generatePresignedUrlRequest.withExpiration(new Date(expiration));
        generatePresignedUrlRequest.addRequestParameter(
                Headers.S3_CANNED_ACL,
                CannedAccessControlList.PublicRead.toString()
        );

        // finally generating URL string
         URL url = s3Client.generatePresignedUrl(generatePresignedUrlRequest);
```

Here is my S3Uploader params

```
  const uploader = new S3Upload({
    getSignedUrl: getSignedUrl,
    uploadRequestHeaders: {'x-amz-acl': 'public-read'},
    contentType: contentType,
    scrubFilename: (filename) => filename.replace(/[^\w\d_\-.]+/ig, ''),
    contentDisposition: 'auto',
    s3path: 'assets/',
    onError:reject,
    onFinishS3Put: resolve,
  })
  uploader.uploadFile(file)
```

As stated this is fine for images, zip files etc.. just times out on video.

Comment: I'm having a similar issue, I posted a question with more code here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71596706/aws-s3-presignedpost-works-locally-but-fails-in-production-with-err-connection-r